# LWUIT : arabic font problem

Tags: java-me, lwuit

Hi
how can i add arabic Characters to bitmap font and show in application ? how can i do it on localization section ?
when i use system font it`s shows seprated and reserved on some phones , i want to make bitmap font to show arabic strings correctly on all phones
thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can't, LWUIT doesn't support Arabic bitmap fonts. Which is related to the fact that Arabic language contains different glyph for each character, which didn't considered while developing the bitmap font in LWUIT.

Comment: System font`s didnt show correctly on sony ericsson and sumsang !!! how can i slove this problem ?

Comment: did you develop arabic application with this library ?

Comment: yes, the SonyEricsson problem is a bug on the device, it is not related to LWUIT and I think it is fixed on newer devices